# Trying to Swap Time from 24 format to 12 hour on GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, time, tkinter

I am trying to swap the outputted time back and forth between 24 and 12 hour formats. The time is ouputted on the gui as text. I have already created my interface, and the button but for some reason my function calls are not responding correctly.

This is my code so far:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import os

class ConfigurationManagement():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__clockMode = 12
        self.__clockColor = ''
        self.__swapButtonTextColor = ''
        self.__swapButtonColor = ''

    def readClockSetting(self):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        print(cwd)
        filename = "clockSetting.txt"
        setting = open(filename, 'r')
        allSetting = setting.readlines()
        setting.close()
        return allSetting

    def setClockMode(self, clockMode):
        self.__clockMode = clockMode

    def setClockColor(self, clockColor):
        self.__clockColor = clockColor

    def setSwapButtonTextColor(self, swapButtonTextColor):
        self.__swapButtonTextColor = swapButtonTextColor

    def setSwapButtonColor(self, swapButtonColor):
        self.__swapButtonColor = swapButtonColor

    def getClockMode(self):
        return self.__clockMode


def settingUpClockSetting():
    global clock
    clock = ConfigurationManagement()
    allSetting = clock.readClockSetting()

    clock.setClockMode(allSetting[3])
    clock.setClockColor(allSetting[6])
    clock.setSwapButtonTextColor(allSetting[9])

def timeIn24(pastTime=''):
    currentTime = time.strftime('%H: %M: %S')
    if currentTime != pastTime:
        digitalClock.config(text=currentTime)
    digitalClock.after(200, timeIn24)


def timeIn12(pastTime=''):
    currentTime = time.strftime('%I: %M: %S')
    if currentTime != pastTime:
        digitalClock.config(text=currentTime)
    digitalClock.after(200, timeIn24)

def clockSwap():
    print("Cat")
    clockMode = clock.getClockMode()
    if clockMode == 12:
        clock.setClockMode(24)
        timeIn24()
    elif clockMode == 24:
        clock.setClockMode(12)
        timeIn12()


settingUpClockSetting()
root = Tk()
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root).pack(side=BOTTOM)
digitalClock = Label(topFrame, font=('times', 100, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='green')
digitalClock.pack()
timeIn12()
root.geometry('700x500')
timeSwapButton = Button(bottomFrame, text="24/12 Modes", fg="red", bg="black", command=clockSwap).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

----------Digital Clock Configuration File----------

```
ClockType[12,24]:
12

ClockColor[The following colors can be handled: ]:
green

SwapButtonTextColor[The following colors can be handled ]:
red

SwapButtonColor[The following colors can be handled: ]:
black
```

I added the cat print to the clockswap function to make sure my button is actually working , and it for sure is.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger? Or, failing that, have you tried adding prints inside both branches of the if in the clockswap() function, and/or printing the value returned by clock.getClockMode()? If you haven't tried these simple debugging options, what are you doing asking a question on StackOverflow?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I actually fixed the problem a second ago myself, and added a new answer to the post :); regardless thanks for helping!

Comment: At least part of the problem is with the `"clockSetting.txt"`configuration file handling. For example you're getting `allSetting[3]` set to the string `'12\n'`, not the integer `12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you keep scheduling new clock updates without stopping the old clock updates. Also, `timeIn12` uses `timeIn24` in the call to `after`.

You don't need two functions to do the updating. Just have a single function do the updating, and all it needs to do is change the format. For example:

```
def updateTime(self):
    if self.getClockMode() == 12:
        currentTime = time.strftime('%I: %M: %S')
    else
        currentTime = time.strftime('%H: %M: %S')
    ...
```

Comment: I had already gotten this fixed(Not sure how to close a question)- you can refer to my latest comment. regardless I am going to mark your response as the answer since I pretty much had done the same to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I just got this fixed,

I added the following function:

```
def clockSwap():
    global counter
    if counter == 24:
        counter = 12
    elif counter == 12:
        counter += 12
    return counter
```

and added both clocks to the same counter:

```
def timeIn24Or12(pastTime=''):

if counter == 12:
    currentTime = time.strftime('%H: %M: %S')
    if currentTime != pastTime:
        digitalClock.config(text=currentTime)
    digitalClock.after(200, timeIn24Or12)
elif counter == 24:
    currentTime = time.strftime('%I: %M: %S')
    if currentTime != pastTime:
        digitalClock.config(text=currentTime)
    digitalClock.after(200, timeIn24Or12)
```